# Как изменить дату создания файла на Андроид?

Tags: java, android

В интернете нашел способ как задать дату создания/последнее изменение/последний доступ в Java. Делается это с помощью интерфейса BasicFileAttributeView, а точнее с помощью его метода setTimes(FileTime lastModifiedTime, FileTime lastAccessTime, FileTime createTime). В Intellij IDEA все сработала. Все три свойства меняются.

Но в Андроиде (Android Studio) это не работает, выбрасывает исключение IOException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException. Все разрешения (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE и READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE и даже попробовал MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) предоставлены.

Если задать в первых двух параметрах метода setTimes null (в принципе это мне и надо), то исключений нет, но дата создания файла не меняется.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка? Как задать дату создания файла в Android?